# eGPU with USB3.0 to train CNN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, gpu

I want to use keras with tensorflow-gpu to train CNN at work.

Since I cannot use cloud GPU server such as AWS, because cannot transfer data outside of intranet, I wanna try to use eGPU.

But the problem is, my office computer doesn’t have thunderbolt3 IF, only have USB3.0 Type-A.
So I have to use an adapter that convert Thunderbolt3 to USB3.0.
Thunderbolt3 has 5GB/sec data transfer speed, but USB3.0 has only 500MB/sec.

Does this speed disadvantage makes any serious mal performance when training CNN?
Currently it tooks 24 hours to train mobilenetV2 with 1400 photos, which size is 244*244.
I would be happy if eGPU makes this in 30 minutes.

Comment: Can you not get a desktop PC? For the cost of an eGPU you almost get a cheap PC.

Comment: Thanks Andreas.

I’d rather buy a eGPU, not a PC.

The reason is that my company has strict security rules and I will be asked for a lot of duty if I own an extra beametal PC.

Comment: You bottleneck you GPU by a factor of 32 compared to PCIe 3.0 x16. So you will have quite a huge performance hit.

Comment: Thanks Andreas.
I agree, and I want to know “how much” does the speed disadvantage hit the performance.

I run a training script on a CPU machine, mobilenetV2 of keras applications with tensorflow.
CPUs have run up to almost 100% during the training, on the other hand the disk access was  moderate since the script just read several photos at once from the disk.
So, data transportation from HDD to GPU’s RAM doesn’t require much speed, I guess.

BUT, this is just a hypothesis and I don’t want to take any risk.
So I’m going to try to buy a PC, as you said.

Comment: If my comment helped you finding a decision please also accept it as the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You bottleneck you GPU by a factor of 32 compared to PCIe 3.0 x16. So you will have quite a huge performance hit. So I would recommend buying a PC.